# Omitting the verb but changing the subject in enumeration

Tags: grammaticality

If I say:

> Alpha denotes the car's speed and Beta [denotes] the acceleration.

Can I omit the second "denotes"?
Is there any rule that justifies this?

The omission sounds good to me in the first sentence, but there are examples which sound bad:

> Alpha is yellow, Beta blue and Delta brown.

Comment: Yes: it's called 'gapped coordination' (or just 'gapping'), where an element (typically a verb) in the middle of a non-initial coordinate is omitted but recoverable from the corresponding part of the initial coordinate.

Comment: @BillJ Is it possible to do the same to a sentence that has multiple clauses like the last sentence, please?

Comment: Yes, it is. But I wouldn't recommend more than three coordinated clauses.

Comment: @BillJ Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for!